# Build neovim offline

Tags: build, cmake, luarocks, neovim

I want to use neovim in an environment with no internet connection. The issue is that the build needs to download many dependancies from various sites across the web, so building there is not an option. I also don't have root privileges on the machine so I can't install a package. The OS is rethat 6.4.

As I see it there are two options:

- Have a way to pull the source of all the dependancies before copying it to the machine, copy and build it! (I don't see a way to do this)
- Find a way to statically link it on another machine and copy it there

Is there any other option? Is there an easy way to do wither of the above?

Comment: If you just do `make` in a clone of the GitHub repository, all dependencies should be linked statically by default. Pre-downloading the dependencies is also possible, but a bit more complicated to explain. It's done that way for the Homebrew formula and the Ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 1):

I use for similar tasks ansible+vm. Build a virtual mashine, with VMWare/vargant/etc and install on this system all dependies, and just copy it.
I did my personal dotfiles with autoinstall all dependies for neovim.

```
...
  - name: software-properties-common
  - name: python-software-properties
  - name: build-essential
  - name: libssl-dev
  - name: exuberant-ctags
  - name: cmake
  - name: python-dev
  - name: python3-dev
  - name: python3.5-dev
  - name: python-pip
  - name: python3-pip
  - name: libxml2-dev
  - name: libxslt-dev
  - name: python3.5
...
```

Full sequence for installation on a clean system here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/asm-jaime/dotfiles/tree/master/conf.ansible)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully build Neovim on RedHat 5.5 with an indirect internet connection. It is a bit awkward but eventually works. I followed https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim and had to install a couple of additional libraries/tools (`cmake` etc.). I don't think the building process is your biggest problem. But Neovim itself is pretty hard to use effectively without a plugin manager which requires an internet connection to checkout plugins from github.